# (Java) Get a specific key / value from a Map by using the classic for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, maps

I have this Map:

Map<String, List<Map<String, Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();

I want to iterate through this Map by using the classic for loop and without using other methods such as Iterator

Thank you!

Comment: Would you like to iterate over the Entries of the map using an index?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can do it. Wrote sample implementation below. Hope it should help.

```
public class TestDummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> temp = new HashMap<>();
        temp.put("harish", 1);
        List<Map<String, Integer>> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        tempList.add(temp);
        Map<String, List<Map<String, Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("shyam", tempList);
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Map<String, Integer>>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("[Key] : " + entry.getKey() + " [Value] : " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be as:

```
[Key] : shyam [Value] : [{harish=1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<Map<String, Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Test", List.of(Map.of("TestValue", 1)));
    map.put("Test2", List.of(Map.of("TestValue2", 2)));

    Object[] entries = map.entrySet().toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(entries[i]);
    }
}
```